# unity3d EntryPointNotFoundException yet entryPoint exists

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I have a C/C++ unmanaged DLL that is working with the exception of a single method which causes an `EntryPointNotFoundException`

i'm setting up the DLL in c#

```
private const string dllname = "mydllname";
[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateBridge();

[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern void DestroyBridge(IntPtr context);

[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern int getChannels(IntPtr context);

[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern void setUpdate(IntPtr context, IntPtr values);
```

and then calling the method

```
IntPtr updatePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(update));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(update, updatePtr, true);
setUpdate(context, updatePtr);
```

Before I'm calling `setUpdate(context, updatePtr)` I'm sucessfully calling `CreateBridge()` and `getChannels(IntPtr context)` so we know the DLL is present, that it is loaded and that other entryPoints can be called

But `setUpdate(context, updatePtr)` causes the exception `EntryPointNotFoundException`

the C definition is as follows

```
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport) 

...

extern "C" {
DLL_EXPORT UnityBridge* CreateBridge();
DLL_EXPORT void DestroyBridge(const UnityBridge* _unitybridge);
DLL_EXPORT int getChannels(UnityBridge* _unitybridge);
DLL_EXPORT void setUpdate(UnityBridge* _unitybridge, Update* update);
}
```

What else can cause this exception?

---

EDIT #1

I checked with Dependency it is not being exported... this makes the question different, but any clues?

Comment: Is the `setUpdate` function *defined* (implemented) in the DLL? Does the definition match the declaration you show (i.e. do you include the header file in the source file, or declare the implementation as `extern "C"`)?

Comment: Try DLL Export viewer (for instance) to check that the setUpdate symbol really is being exported from the DLL.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, the function is defined, has matching signatures etc and the source files are correct - they are the same as for the other methods that are working

Comment: @john I've just checked with Dependency Walker and your instinct is right here, it's not being exported - updated question to reflect - any idea why that might be?

Comment: @garrilla The most likely reason for it not being exported is that you haven't defined it right. Missing out `extern "C"` for instance.

Comment: @john well it's in an `extern "C"` block with the other working methods (as per the question) and all signatures and definitions match. But it gives me a good starting point for further investigation!

Comment: @garrilla That means nothing unless you are also include that header file where you define the setUpdate function.